# Replicate API invoked by ibmcloud CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud

How do replicate the outcome of the CLI command : 
     ibmcloud  resource search 'service_name:logdnaat

via an API?
I have figured the https://resource-controller.cloud.ibm.com/v2/resource_instances, but i don't understand the way I can apply the filter like in CLI to filter by service_name.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. All CLI commands are based on the [(documented) IBM Cloud APIs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs). You can use `IBMCLOUD_TRACE=true` to even trace your CLI command.

`IBMCLOUD_TRACE=true ibmcloud resource search 'service_name:logdnaat` would print out how the actual search is performed. It boils down to the [Global Search and Tagging API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/search#gs-intro) and its [search function](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/search#find-instances-of-resources-267b7c).